# An algebraic word problem worth a second look

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

Ed filled $2/3$ of his radiator with antifreeze and then added $4$ more quarts (a gallon) of antifreeze. After draining half the antifreeze, he needed $11$ quarts of antifreeze to fill the radiator to capacity. How many gallons of antifreeze can the radiator hold?

To me the equation was : $$x - \left(\frac{\frac{2}{3}x+4}{2}\right)+11=x,$$ but the contest solutions on one online link said it was only $$\left(\frac{2}{3}x+4\right)+11=x$$ where $x$ is total capacity in gallons.  I don't see why. Can someone explain ?

Comment: Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 5):

Both of these solutions are wrong.

Let $x$ denote the capacity of the radiator in gallons.

We start with $\frac23x$ and add $1$ gallon, so we have $\frac23x+1$. Then we drain half, so we're left with $\frac12\left(\frac23x+1\right)$. Then we add $\frac{11}4$ more gallons, and the result is the full capacity, i.e. $x$. Thus

$$
\frac12\left(\frac23x+1\right)+\frac{11}4=x\;.
$$

Comment: Ah i c ! I forgot the second solution was ((2/3(x)+1)/2)+11 = x then after finding x it was converted to gallons by dividing by 4 as u did . The glitch i wasnt seeing was when it said " half the antifreeze " means u subtract from the TOTAL antifreeze * not * the total capacity which is x ! So its the antifreeze part which was in parenthese and when u subtract that from total antifreeze u end up with the same expression !:) ((2/3(x)+ 4)/2) right ? Thats where i glitched i think ..tricky tricky :)

Comment: But, if $x$ is the capacity in quarts, the second displayed equation is correct.

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss: I'm afraid I don't follow you. I see neither what you refer to by "the antifreeze part" nor by "the same expression", nor what you are "dividing by $4$". Please write with clear antecedents.

Comment: @DavidHill: a) The problem statement says twice that $x$ is the capacity in gallons. b) Even if $x$ were the capacity in quarts, the second displayed equation would be missing a factor $\frac12$.

Comment: Joriki if x is in quarts u need only divide that by 4 after solving for it . I hope to study math in berlin next year , are you there still ?

Comment: True it needed the factor of 1/2

Comment: I finally see why its not ×- blah blah ( x minus blah blah )  ..its because ed is taking out ( subtracting ) 1/2 the antifreeze , NOT the entire concoction which would be x 